# C system() call fails with error "unterminated string"

Tags: c

I have a small piece of c code which should run an awk command on my linux machine. However for the life of me it will not exec. The awk works if I directly run it in the terminal.

My current failed command

```
system("awk '{ printf \"%d \n\", $12 }' results.dat | sort -n");
```

It fails with

```
awk: { printf "%d 
awk:          ^ unterminated string
```

How else do you escape the double quotes so that the command will run? Also why does this fail, but when I replace the system call with a printf it will print?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you should escape the `\n` again, as in

```
system("awk '{ printf \"%d \\n\", $12 }' results.dat | sort -n");
//                         ^ note the extra \
```

as I think the `\n` is meant to be part of the `printf`.

Your current construction calls `system` with an argument of

```
awk '{ printf "%d 
", $12 }' results.dat | sort -n
```

Comment: just gonna shoot myself now... Thanks.

Comment: @corymatthews: np; sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes :]